# CSS Error parsing

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I tested Java 8u40. I get error when I run this part of the code:

```
setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FAFAFA, #EAEAEA);"
            + " -fx-border: 2px solid; -fx-border-color: white;");

X 15, 2014 10:33:53 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FAFAFA, #EAEAEA); -f
x-border: 2px solid; -fx-border-color: white;}: expected series of <size> while parsing '-fx-border'
 at [1,82]
```

Is this a bug or css code is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You should define every border property for itself as specified in ["JavaFX CSS Reference Guide"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).

```
-fx-border-width: 2px;
-fx-border-style: solid;
-fx-border-color: white;
```

Instead of

```
-fx-border: 2px solid white;
```

or

```
-fx-border: 2px solid; -fx-border-color: white;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look's like problem with `-fx-border`. Maybe you need to specify a full shorthand '-fx-border' property. Try to set:

```
-fx-border: 2px solid white;
```

Instead of

```
-fx-border: 2px solid; -fx-border-color: white;
```